# How does Boost.Lambda work?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I was wondering how boost implemented the Lambda library. I was digging into the implementation but it felt like i'm falling down the rabbit hole...

Can someone please explain shortly how the following code snippet works (Taken from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/windows.html))?

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

What's going on behind the scenes that creates a functor object that expects an int?

Thanks

Comment: Probably expression templates - something along the lines of `template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs> multiply_functor<Lhs, Rhs> operator*(const Lhs& lhs, const Rhs& rhs);`, where `multiply_functor` determines the unbound parameters by detecting placeholders like `_1`.

Comment: If you are using a compiler supporting C++11 then you are better off learning lambdas the Standard Way (TM)